# Can I use the mongodb ref to reference a model in that same model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let assume I have a model called `Task` that has a field called `dependencies` and the `dependencies` field is of type mongodb ID and I will like it to be a reference to the `Task` model itself. I don't know if this is possible with mongodb and mongoose.

For Example:

```js
// Task model
const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
// other fields

// dependencies: [{
  types: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  ref: 'Task' // is this possible?at what cost?
}]

})

modules.export = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, nesting is possible in the MongoDB and in the mongoose as well. Try to avoid depth.

Comment: What do you mean by depth?